# MongoDB on Ubuntu weird error ^?ELF^B^A^A

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, forever

I was running MongoDB successfully on an Ubuntu server along with my nodeJS application. But for some reason I get following error in my mongodb-log when I start it with `forever start /path/to/mongod`:

```
/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.5/bin/mongod:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ^?ELF^B^A^A^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

I removed the mongodb directory and installed it again, but I still get the same error.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forever` is only meant to node.js-based modules. `mongod` is a binary (i.e. in ELF format, do `file $(which mongod)` to verify this for yourself) and cannot be handled by `forever`.

What you see is `forever` trying to use node to start a node module called `mongo`and failing to compile the js code (since it is reading a ELF header).

You will have to rely on your system's init system as for regular daemons.  I would [start reading here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#control-scripts) for how to proceed.

Comment: it makes sense since running mongod alone works fine, thank you